# How to prevent IDLE from running a Python code prematurely

Tags: python, python-idle

I am quite new in using IDLE, and yes this is a rookie question, but please bear with me. I have this long, complex python code (I will embed below), that I am copying line by line to IDLE. The problem is that IDLE program runs some parts of the code before I am done typing the whole code. This happens when I skip two lines at a certain section of the code. When I copy the same code as is and input it in one of the online Python interpreters, it runs just fine and the output is complete, unlike with IDLE, where it is in bits or incomplete. How do I stop IDLE from running the code early? The code runs at line 25 (counter += 1) after skipping two lines (so that I get back to the initial/default indentation starting with ">>>"). Here is the code:

````
decimal_parts = []
for num in decimal_numbers:
    decimal_part = str(num).split('.')[1] if '.' in str(num) else '00'
    if len(decimal_part) == 1:
        decimal_part += '0'
    decimal_parts.append(decimal_part)

lst = list(map(int, ",".join(decimal_parts).split(',')))
start_index = 0
counter = 1
grouped_lists = []

for i, num in enumerate(lst):
    if num == 0:
        start_index = i
        print(f"Position: {i + 1}")
        sub_list = lst[start_index:] + lst[:start_index]
        four_index = sub_list.index(0)
        last_digit_list = [num % 10 for num in sub_list[four_index:]]
        print(f"List {counter}: {last_digit_list}")
        grouped_lists.append(last_digit_list)
        counter += 1

matches = {}
for i, sub_list in enumerate(grouped_lists):
    for j, num in enumerate(sub_list):
        if num not in matches:
            matches[num] = [i]
        else:
            matches[num].append(i)

for num, match_indices in matches.items():
    if len(match_indices) > 1:
        print(f"Matches found for number {num} in lists: {match_indices}")```


Irrespective of the code running prematurely, I continued inputting the rest of the code, then after the output was generated, I would continue typing the other sections, however, I don't want bits of outputs from bits of code. I want to be able to type the whole code, and get the whole output, all in once. Anyways, after "counter +=" line, there is another section of the code I still need to type on a new line starting with ">>>", but I never get to this line as the code runs.
````

Comment: IDLE's shell imitates interactive Python, also know as the Python REPL.  Both run each statement when entered and recognized.  To run multiple statements at once, enter them in the editor, save, and run -- as suggested in Blazing Blast's answer.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules already?

Comment: IDLE runs code when it encounters a blank line. You could remove blank lines in your code, e.g. the line beore `matches = {}`. You should just use a regular python script and run it by calling `python file.py`, but if you _really_ want a REPL, consider [`ipython`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The IDLE shell is just an interpreter, you can send multi-line blocks of code at once by using <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd> when starting a new line, but instead it is recommended to run a Python file instead. To do this you make a new file by pressing <kbd>Control + N</kbd> or going to *File* -> *New file*. Now copy all text into that new file and run it by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or by going to *Run* -> *Run module*. It may ask you to save your file first, if it does, press *Ok* and select a location.

Comment: Thanks a great deal! This solution worked perfectly. I'm now able to run the whole complex code, as a whole, and get all the results (outputs) in full. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to have helped, you can mark my answer as correct if you want.

Answer (score -3):

What version of IDLE are you using? You might be needing to update it to the latest version. Also, be wary of indentation and spacing. You can adjust indentation on IDLE's general settings and switch off automatic indentations... hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).